# Weird anomalies on multiple material texture baking

Tags: materials, texture-baking, error

I am new to blender so bear with me.

So I've been testing baking textures on models with multiple materials and it usually goes fine but this time after the bake was completed there were weird anomalies on the finished texture. Some parts were brighter, some parts were completely colored wrong and I don't understand why.

I have the blend file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/7fd1e2824ec6469585b849ee35db8a60

[image: Left: Model with multiple materials. Right: Model with only the baked texture applied to it.]

[image: Left: Backside of the model with only the baked texture applied to it. Right: Backside of model with multiple materials.]
[image: Baking settings.]

Comment: Hello, you don't share your high poly nor your normal map, but I see that you have custom split normals, maybe your problem comes from here? Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: @moonboots YEP that completely fixed the issue. Livesaver. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have custom split normals, which can happen with imported FBX, it causes weird shadings, go into *Object Data > Geometry Data >* and press on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.